# How to load an image from a json response field in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am using the Twitch API, that offers an API call that responds with an image and game name. I want to display the image and the game name under, however the image is not loading:

PicsNotLoading:

[image]

```
 render() {
    const { game } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="GameImage">
          <img src= {game.box_art_url} alt=""/>
          <p>{game.name} </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GameImage
```

Comment: Can you provide the image URL that is not loading and what the `game` object looks like? This looks correct, although I'd remove the space between src and your expression, `<img src={game.box_art_url} alt=""/>`

Comment: Not sure, but the URL from `game.box_art_url` seems to be incorrect. Could you please verify it?

Comment: @JamesIves the image URL's are provided using the "box_art_url" object. If you look at the errors in the console on the right side, the URLS for each game are shown but not connecting.

Comment: @mpasko256 It seems correct, due to the console on the right side showing each games URL, just not displaying it. The game.name object loads obviously, due to the game names showing up.

Comment: @jpatt but `404` says the opposite...

Comment: @mpasko256 the URLs seem to be connecting but not displaying, unlike the game.name call, game.box_art_url is an object. Maybe using img src isn't correct for an object response field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL was valid your code would work, but the image you're using is 404ing. I'm not familiar with the Twitch API at all, but looking at the [documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/) it seems like you need to replace the `{width}` and `{height}` parameters in the path.

You can see this more clearly in the payload as the URL isn't encoded like it is when the browser 404s the request.

```
{
  "data":
  [{
     "id": "493057",
     "name": "PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS",
     "box_art_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/PLAYERUNKNOWN%27S%20BATTLEGROUNDS-{width}x{height}.jpg"
  }]
}
```

This is how you might achieve something like this, replace the `width` and `height` variables in the `formatImageUrl` method to your desired height and width and it will generate a valid URL.

```
class GameImage extends React.Component

 formatImageUrl(url) {
    const width = '400'
    const height = '400'

    return url.replace('{width}', width).replace('{height}', height)
 }

 render() {
    const { game } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="GameImage">
          <img src={this.formatImageUrl(game.box_art_url)} alt=""/>
          <p>{game.name} </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GameImage
```

Here's the formatted URL:

`https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/PLAYERUNKNOWN%27S%20BATTLEGROUNDS-400x400.jpg`

Hope that helps!